# How to derive the simplest 1D Superpotential Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, supersymmetry, hamiltonian

In the [superpotential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpotential) wiki article there are definitions of two supersymmetric operators:
$$Q_1=\frac{1}{2}\left[(p-iW)b+(p+iW)b^\dagger\right] \\
Q_2=\frac{i}{2}\left[(p-iW)b-(p+iW)b^\dagger\right] $$

Then the following Hamiltonian is defined and presented:

$$H=\{Q_1,Q_1\}=\{Q_2,Q_2\}=\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{W^2}{2}+\frac{W'}{2}(bb^\dagger-b^\dagger b)$$

Where $W' = \frac{dW(x)}{dx}$ and $\{b,b^\dagger\}=1$ and $[b,b^\dagger]=0$.

1. Why does $=\{Q_1,Q_1\}=\{Q_2,Q_2\}=\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{W^2}{2}+\frac{W'}{2}(bb^\dagger-b^\dagger b)$ hold?
2. What's the motivation/justification to define the superpotential as such? Also why do $Q_1, Q_2$ map "bosonic" states into "fermionic" states and vice versa?
3. Lastly, why does it take the form: $H = \frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{W^2}{2} \pm \frac{W'}{2}$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/458179/2451